# Multiple files declaration order

Tags: javascript, declaration

I'm building a game in javascript, and I have multiple files. The main file game.js contains `var Game = {};` at the beginning, and, for example, upgrades.js contains `Game.Upgrades = {};` at the beginning. Now, I used to do `let item = Game.Upgrades;` at the start of each function, so instead of doing `Game.Upgrades.upgradeName.cost` every time in that function, for example, I'd do `item.upgradeName.cost`, or even `let item = Game.Upgrades[key];` if I'm looping through all upgrades, or if the functions parameter is passing the key (`function buyUpgrade(key) where key = upgradeName`), so now I can just call `item.cost;` and save myself some typing.

Now I was thinking, why declare `let item = Game.Upgrades;` in every function, when I could just declare it once, right after the `Game.Upgrades = {};`, so I did add `const UPG = Game.Upgrades;` right after I declared the Upgrades object. So now I can just use `UPG.upgradeName.cost;` every time in my code without having to do `let item = Game.Upgrades;` in every function. This would be a better solution right? Since every declaration uses a bit of memory, right?

Strange thing is, if I declare `const UPG = Game.Upgrades;` below the `var Game = {};` in the main file, it doesn't work... But, when declared below the `Game.Upgrades = {};` it does, which confuses me, as `Game.Upgrades = {};` is basically just `Game = { Upgrades: {} };`

Also, if I declare the const in the upgrades.js file, since it gets loaded after the game.js file, would I be able to use that const in the game.js file? For now it works OK, but is this a good practice? I know I can't do this with let.

Should I just pile up everything in my main game.js file and start everything from there?

All these things with var, let and const are seriously making me so confused. I know I should avoid using var, hence I only use it to declare my Game object. I use let inside functions, but since all of my `let`-s are basically newCost, or newDps calculations, figured I'd change them all to const as well.

Any insight? I used JSlint the other day with my code and it only gave me more headache.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could edit your question into a more abbreviated and precise format, I bet you'll get answers.

Comment: It doesn't matter that they are in different files. Surely you understand the difference between `var Game = {}; const UPG = Game.Upgrades; Game.Upgrades = {};` and `var Game = {}; Game.Upgrades = {}; const UPG = Game.Upgrades;`?

Comment: The best practice is probably to use ES6 modules and import everything explicitly.